# Encapsulated Group by or conditional aggregation in Vertica DB

Tags: sql, group-by, vertica

I have the following table in a Vertica DB:

```
+---------+-------+
| Readout | Event |
+---------+-------+
|       1 | A     |
|       1 | B     |
|       1 | A     |
|       2 | B     |
|       2 | A     |
+---------+-------+
```

I would like to group each readout and count the frequency of the events, resulting in a table like this:

```
+---------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| Readout | Count(Readout) | Count(Event A) | Count (Event B) |
+---------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|       1 |              3 |              2 |               1 |
|       2 |              2 |              1 |               1 |
+---------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

I am sure there is an easy `GROUP BY` command, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select readout, count(*),
       sum(case when event = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as num_a,
       sum(case when event = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as num_b
from t
group by readout;
```

Comment: Epic, works like a charm, thanks a lot! Follow up questions: Do I have to specify the Names of the events? What if I want to do it for all event names in the table, for the case if I don't have a list of all possible events that are in the table.

Comment: @valenzio . . . If you don't have the list of events, then you might need dynamic SQL.  I don't think Vertica even supports `crosstab()`.

Comment: I am running the commands in python, so I can make a first querry, were I would get a list of the events (DISTINCT) . And than use a for loop to build the query that you suggested.